# How to create mercurial tag with a space

Tags: mercurial, tags

I would like to tag a changeset in Mercurial to 'Distribution 1.0'.
Unfortunatly I cannot find a **command line** command for creating a tag with a space in it's name.
When I use `hg tag -m "Distribution 1.0"` (double quotes) I get the help for the hg tag command indicating that I have an error.
When I use `hg tag -m 'Distribution 1.0'` a tag with the name `1.0'` (single quotes) is created.

I know some tools don't like spaces alltogether, but if I edit my .hgtags file I can create a tag with a space.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `hg tag "Distribution 1.0"`.  The `-m` option provides the message for the commit that creates the tag, so you can use both:  `hg tag "Distribution 1.0" -m "Distribution 1.0"`.